# Can't center both vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

I just can't center the div(Horizontal-Container)both vertically and horizontally and I can't figure out why it's not working...

I've try all the methods by w3school, but either it's not horizontally or vertically center, it can't be both achieved...

Below is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #62306D;
}

.Horizontal-Container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.Yellow {
  background-color: #F7EC7D;
  width: 90px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Horizontal-Container">
  <div class="Yellow"></div>
  <div class="Yellow"></div>
  <div class="Yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your items are centered. With `height: auto;` why are you expecting the container to be higher than their content??? You explicitly command the container to be only as high as what is **in it**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your issue arises from `.Horizontal-Container` not being full height so it is technically vertically centered, just it hasn't moved. To fix this, you need to set the `height` of `body` and `html` to `100%` which then allows the container to have the height you desire. It may seem off centre now, but that is down to padding and margin on the elements which you can easily remove.

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #62306D;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

.Horizontal-Container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.Yellow {
  background-color: #F7EC7D;
  width: 90px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Horizontal-Container">
  <div class="Yellow"></div>
  <div class="Yellow"></div>
  <div class="Yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not working because your `.Horizontal-Container` does not have a specific `height`. If you set the `height` to `auto` it will consume as much space as its children need. Thus you have to add a `height` either to your container or simply to your `body` in order to center your elements over the whole page.

```css
body {
  background-color: #62306D;
}

.Horizontal-Container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; /* <-- set a specific height */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.Yellow {
  background-color: #F7EC7D;
  width: 90px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Horizontal-Container">
  <div class="Yellow"></div>
  <div class="Yellow"></div>
  <div class="Yellow"></div>
</div>
```